# bash: ./Main.js: Permission denied On heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, hosting

I'm trying to host a program on Heroku, but whenever I start it, I get an error stating:

```
bash: ./Main.js: Permission denied
 Process exited with status 126
```

I have set up the `Procfile` containing

```
node ./Main.js
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the full contents of your `Procfile`. The error message and the partial snippet don't seem to match.

Comment: Is `Main.js` in the root directory or in a subdirectory, e.g.: `/src`, etc?

Comment: @AlanFriedman all in the root directory.

Comment: @Chris yet the text above is the entire content of the procfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Procfile` contains only

```
node ./Main.js
```

it is malformed. The `Procfile` isn't a script, it is a file that defines process types in [a specific format](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format). If `Main.js` listens for HTTP requests you probably want

```
web: node ./Main.js
```

If not, you probably want

```
worker: node ./Main.js
```

However, the error you are currently getting is probably stemming from your `package.json`. Do you have a start script, e.g. something like this?

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "./Main.js"
    }
}
```

[Heroku will run your start script as a `web` process in the absence of a `Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script) and `Main.js` probably isn't executable. You may be able to fix your problem by changing your start script to run *`node`*, not your script:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./Main.js"
    }
}
```